# appending values each time when calling JNI method

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface

i am using a JNI to fetch signature of apk and i am getting it very well. when i calling this method from java first time i am getting the exact value. calling it again i am getting appended values with exact value  (eg 1234456123456). PFB the code which i am using

```
char* getSignatureMd5(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj)
{
    char* sign = loadSignature(env, obj);
    MD5_CTX context = { 0 };
    MD5Init(&context);
    MD5Update(&context, (unsigned char*)sign, strlen(sign));
    unsigned char dest[16] = { 0 };
    MD5Final(dest, &context);
    int i;
    static char destination[32]={0};
    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            sprintf(destination, "%s%02x", destination, dest[i]);
    }
    return destination;
}
```

getToken JNI method

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_sign_signaturecapturesbi_MyAdapter_getToken(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
                                                                     {
    char* signValue = getSignatureMd5(env, obj);
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, "MyApp", "signValue %s", signValue);
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, signValue);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These lines cause undefined behavior:

```
for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        sprintf(destination, "%s%02x", destination, dest[i]);
}
```

[man 3 printf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fprintf.3.html):

> C99 and POSIX.1-2001 specify that the results are undefined if a call
>   to `sprintf()`, `snprintf()`, `vsprintf()`, or `vsnprintf()` would cause
>   copying to take place between objects that overlap (e.g., if the
>   target string array and one of the supplied input arguments refer to
>   the same buffer).

Moreover `destination` is `static` and because of this it keeps its content between calls. Together these points give you such a weird behavior.

Since `dest` size is well known, you can simply unroll loop, also don't forget to add one extra cell to `destination` for terminating `\0`. And, if possible, you should use `snprintf()` instead:

```
static char destination[33];

snprintf(destination, sizeof destination,
    "%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x"
    "%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x",
    dest[0], dest[1], dest[2], dest[3],
    dest[4], dest[5], dest[6], dest[7],
    dest[8], dest[9], dest[10], dest[11],
    dest[12], dest[13], dest[14], dest[15]);
```

In this case you can leave `destination` as `static` one, since your code doesn't relay on its content anymore. But note that `getSignatureMd5()` returns pointer to the same buffer each time you call it, as result subsequent calls erase result obtained by previous calls.